# Python Pandas : groupby by column and size of groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas dataframe:

```
column1     column2
   1           1
   1           2
   1           3
   1           4
   1           5
   2           6
   2           7
   3           8
```

and need to groupby it by column1 but if the group has more than 2 elements, divide it. And then apply an ngroup function, resulting in:

```
column1     column2     column3
   1           1           0
   1           2           0
   1           3           1
   1           4           1
   1           5           2
   2           6           3
   2           7           3
   3           8           4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with integer division by `2` for helper `Series` and pass to `groupby` for [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
s = df.groupby('column1').cumcount() // 2

df['column3'] = df.groupby([s, 'column1'], sort=False).ngroup()
print (df)
   column1  column2  column3
0        1        1        0
1        1        2        0
2        1        3        1
3        1        4        1
4        1        5        2
5        2        6        3
6        2        7        3
7        3        8        4
```

Comment: this is the first time that I see one of your posts, but I already love them :P